# Creating a file with write.table and file.choose on Mac

Tags: r, macos, write.table

I am a PC user and have used the write.table (and write.csv) extensively. 
I am teaching students how to use R, but some of them use a Mac.

On a PC, the following code:

> write.table(mydata, file.choose(), row.names=F, col.names=T)

opens up a browser window, allowing the user to specify the folder where to save the new file, and specify the file name and extension. (Strangely enough, the user is then prompted to click the button "Open" to create a file.)

On a Mac however, it appears there is no way of specifying the name and extension of the file being created, once the window opens. In other words, there does not seem to be a way to actually create a file.
Am I missing something?

Is the solution simply to replace the "file.choose()"
with the full path to the new file?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, thanks for the comment. Yes, you are correct, but still the fact is our problem was not with Windows (because I have no problem creating the file), but with MacOS. I will definitely try out the "new=TRUE" - on my PC it makes no difference apparently, and I cannot try it on a Mac at the moment. You think this will solve the problem?
With respect to the link you provided - what exactly am I looking at...? Thanks!

Comment: 1) I actually did use TRUE and FALSE in the course for students, but used T and F here for brevity. But can you explain you consider it bad? Just because it isn't explicit, or for some other reason?
2) I'm sorry, but I don't follow what you refer to with respect to calling the function properly.
3) Are you referring to the rpwnd package? My questions still pertains to the use of write.table function in base package.

Comment: Again, are you referring to the "new" parameter being set to TRUE (new=TRUE)? If so, the student tried that on a Mac, still without success.

Comment: See the "answer". Hopefully another R class will talk about applying the scientific method to triaging as well.

Comment: Many thanks, this helped!

Comment: they also fixed it almost immediately so the fix will be in the final 1.2 release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LGTM:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Having said that, if your student is using RStudio then you would normally need to go to their github repo and file an issue but I've already done that https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3903. They seem to intercept the call and pass it to Qt which is not honoring it (it's **not** a macOS issue but a Qt issue).